# How to use Phonegap SoftKeyboard Plugin for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an Android application using [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/). I need to make the softkeyboard appear programatically. I am using the SoftKeyboard plugin which is found [here](https://github.com/nikhilben/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard). Can anyone tell me how to properly include this plugin & make it work? I have tried the tutorial found on the [Phonegap Wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708611/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android), but the plugin is not working.

**[Update]** I have added the plugin to the path

`com/zenexity/SoftKeyBoardPlugin/SoftKeyBoard.java`

Updated `plugins.xml` and included

```
<plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="com.zenexity.SoftKeyBoardPlugin.SoftKeyBoard"/>
```

Then in the `www` folder added `softkeyboard.js`, and  the following in `index.html`

```
plugins.SoftKeyBoard.show(function () {
    // success
},function () {
   // fail
});
```

But nothing happens, the keyboard is not displaying..

Comment: @Nanne nothing happens, no keyboard displaying !

Comment: and did you put anything in the success/fail parts to debug if it accutally faisl or not/

Comment: Yes, have tested with alerts, but nothing happening

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I got SoftKeyBoard working in my application.

**DroidGap Side**

- create /src/com/phonegap/plugins/SoftKeyboard with provided file SoftKeyBoard.java inside
- add to /res/xml/plugins.xml:

  `< plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="com.phonegap.plugins.SoftKeyboard.SoftKeyBoard" />`

**`/assets/www` Side**

- add provided file softkeyboard.js to /assets/www/js
- add to index.html in the head where your other javascripts are included after you have included the phonegap javascript:

  `< script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/softkeyboard.js"></script>`

You can then call the following if you are on device or using something like Ripple:

```
window.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.show(function () {
  // success
},function () {
  // fail
});
```

or something like this if you want to make sure the namespace is available, which will prevent undefined problems:

```
((((window || {}).plugins || {}).SoftKeyBoard || {}).show || function(){})();
```

I think maybe where you went wrong was not including the js/softkeyboard.js in your head of index.html.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Its working but how to know the keyboard hide and show event? i used this code ((((window || {}).plugins || {}).SoftKeyBoard || {}).show || function(){})();

Comment: How to call the above function `onfocus` or `onclick `of an `EditText`   in javascript?

Comment: In my case, the keyboard is displayed and then suddenly gets disappeared. Why this happens?

Comment: having the same problem as the comment above, any idea?

Answer (score 9):

For the latest version of PhoneGap (Apache Cordova 2.1.0) I had to do the following:

Installed these plugin sources which reflected the project name change:
https://github.com/originalgremlin/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard

- Copy softkeyboard.js to your javascript library directory.
- Copy SoftKeyBoard.java to src/org/apache/cordova/plugins/SoftKeyBoard.java

Put this in your HTML file, after including the cordova.js file:

```
<script src="/path/to/javascripts/softkeyboard.js"></script>
```

Add this to the bottom of the res/xml/config.xml plugins section:

```
<plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard" />
```

Now, assuming this HTML:

```
<button id="keyboard">Toggle Keyboard</button>
```

This jQuery should do something useful:

```
var softkeyboard = window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard;
$('#keyboard').toggle(softkeyboard.show, softkeyboard.hide);
```

Comment: keyboard dissappears after calling it? any idea? using iscrollview, cordova 2.9.0, jqm 1.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
SoftKeyBoard.show(function () {
    // success
},function () {
   // fail
});
```

The code in the JS file does not put it in the "plugins" namespace.

Orjust use the PhoneGap plugins full namespace:

```
window.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.show(function () {
    // success
},function () {
   // fail
});
```

Answer (score 0):

go through the link. here is the full project:--

[SoftKeyboardPlugin by Simon McDonald](https://github.com/macdonst/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard)

Answer (score 0):

**Cordova 3.0 + JQM 1.3.2:** Changing "fullscreen" to "false" in config.xml fixed the "adjustPan" and prevented my inputs from being covered when the keyboard displayed. However, blur() would not close the keyboard and this plugin worked wonderfully.

For the almost latest version of phonegap:

- Add SoftKeyBoard.java to your app package in src
- Add softkeyboard.js to assets/www
- Update config.xml with: 
  `<feature name="SoftKeyBoard"><param name="android-package" value="com.yourAppPackage" /></feature>`
- Call your plugin: `plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function() {//success }, function() {//fail });`