# show/hide softkeyboard plugin for Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an Android application using Phonegap and used  the SoftKeyboard plugin which is found [here](https://github.com/nikhilben/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard) and use this plugins under the guidence of [How to use Phonegap SoftKeyboard Plugin for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060658/how-to-use-phonegap-softkeyboard-plugin-for-android) this link.its working fine.

i used this code `((((window || {}).plugins || {}).SoftKeyBoard || {}).show || function(){})();` to prevent the undefined problem..

My problem is  i need to know the keyboard hide and show event how to find out this?

Comment: Hey buddy, Can you share your code snippet for above `softkeyboard.js` problem? I also referred the same link that you posted above, but in my case it's not working and I'm stuck at this situation.

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin

> https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard

Install plugin by using this command.

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard.git

It will automatically place all necessary files to proper place and change configurations. Use like

> SoftKeyboard.show();
>
> SoftKeyboard.hide();