# How do I use PhoneGap's soft keyboard (org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard)?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm writing my first PhoneGap app, and I need to make the keyboard appear and disappear programmatically. Unfortunately, it's not working, but I wonder if I'm doing it correctly. Here's the state of things:

I used `$ cordova plugin search keyboard` to find this plugin at the command line, and then I installed it like this:

`$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard" via plugin registry
Installing "org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard" for android`

Based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957828/3614438), I then added this line to my config.xml:

`<plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.SoftKeyBoard" />`

I put softkeyboard.js in myapp/www/js/, and I referenced it in the html like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/softkeyboard.js"></script>`

After installing, SoftKeyboard.java appeared in myapp/plugins/org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard . But just for good measure I also put a copy in myapp/src/org/apache/cordova/plugin/ .

Finally, I added these to my html:

`<button id="keyboard">Toggle Keyboard</button>`

and

`<script>
   var softkeyboard = window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard;
   $('#keyboard').toggle(softkeyboard.show, softkeyboard.hide);
</script>`

As you might have guessed, nothing happened when I rebuilt and clicked the button. What should I be doing differently?

Thanks!

P.S. - After seeing plugin (singular) and plugins (plural) used in so many SO answers, I renamed everything both ways and that didn't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding plugin with `cordova add plugin` command, it's not necessary to include plugin's js file. You only need to include cordova.js (I think you have already done that, but better to clarify):

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>`

After adding plugin, you should build or prepare project to get plugin in action. Cordova cli tool will copy the javascript and native (android, ios, etc) codes into `platforms/%platform_name%` directory. Plugins will not work in browser mostly, but never in `/www` directory (as there should be no cordova.js inside that dir).

I think the problem here is jQuery toggle function that you use. It is actually a function for toggling display state of the element. (see: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

This will work when you emulate or run your android app.

```
<script>
   var isKeyboardShown = false;
   var softkeyboard = window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard;
   $('#keyboard').click(function() {
       (isKeyboardShown = !isKeyboardShown) ? softkeyboard.show() : softkeyboard.hide();
   });
</script>
```