# Manually Show/Hide Device keyboard in JavaScript

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Can I manually show/hide device keyboard?

My application is behaving strangely if device keyboard is on display and, say, I  hit next button then the CSS of jQuery Mobile is getting distorted. I am not getting any javascript or any other error in the console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060658/how-to-use-phonegap-softkeyboard-plugin-for-android

Comment: What is "Next" button? in the keyboard, or a next button that navigates away to another page in your app? Please explain the scenario so that it could be reproduced.

Comment: Its the 'Next' button on the page that navigates away to another page in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used one of the suggestions in the following question (the one with 84 up votes...), and it worked well for me: [iPad Safari - Make keyboard disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937339/ipad-safari-make-keyboard-disappear)

Lets assume you have an `<input type="text" id="myInput" />`.

So in your change page code you can do the following, which will first dismiss the keyboard and then perform the page navigation:

```
function changeToPage1() {
    $("#myInput").blur();
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','page1.html');
}
```

Tested in iOS Simulator but should work in Android as well.

Comment: I have made the changes. So far it looks good. Since it was a random issue, I cannot tell right now whether it worked or not. I will update the comment once I am done with the testing.

Comment: I think its working now. I have tested in 5 different devices. Thanks for the solution.