# how to show a keyboard when there was an input field in application dynamically in android mobiles using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

in my application I have an input field whenever I goes to that input field page I need to show the keyboard dynamically in android mobiles using jquery for this I tried

$('#appear').focus();

Hear the problem is the focus is showing in the input field but the keyboard is not appearing. I don't understand what is the exact problem. So please suggest an approach for this problem as it is very important to my application.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't appear directly possible but it seems there are workarounds.

See here: [jQuery Mobile Show Keyboard on Input Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362066/jquery-mobile-show-keyboard-on-input-focus)

and here: [Show virtual keyboard on mobile phones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript)