# jQuery mobile framework on page load show softkeyboard

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a `index.html` page..

The contents in it are 2 textboxes `username` and `password`.

What I need is on page load itself get the focus on to the first textbox and show softkeyboard...

I would like to get it in jquery mobile,also would like to know how it is done for kendo as well?

Comment: have you tried `$('#firstInputId').focus();`?

Comment: yes....it didnt help...

Comment: It doesn't focus on input? or the keyboard doesn't come up?

Comment: @ABertil can u make a fiddle for ur problm at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @hungerpain the keyboard doesnt come up...no need of a fiddle..i have only 2 textboxes and on pageinit i need to get focus and the keyboard showing

Comment: @James..it foucuses on input but keyboar doesnt comes up

Comment: @ABertil ok..is it working on the desktop browsers?

Comment: @hungerpain how can i test in desktop browser...??i am testing in mobile and the softkeyboard doesnt come up..

Comment: No I don't mean the keyboard. I meant the focus on the textbox. The cursor (I) symbol in the text box on desktop === getting keyboard on mobiles.

Comment: @hungerpain cursor symbol in my mobile comes but the keyboard doesnt popup..once i click oon the textbox only the softkeyboard pop ups

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33608/discussion-between-hungerpain-and-abertil)

Comment: it doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done using purely JavaScript unless there is phone gap, refer this below link

[jQuery Mobile Show Keyboard on Input Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362066/jquery-mobile-show-keyboard-on-input-focus)

Comment: its mentioned about ios..i need it in android

Comment: any other ideas to crack this?

Answer (score 0):

For autofocus feature you can either use native feature of HTML5 by giving autofocus attribute to input

```
<input name="username" autofocus>
```

Comment: Autofocus doesn't trigger keyboard on page load, user has to click or tap somewhere at least. That's how mobile browsers work.